# Unlimited Exercise

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have 5 groups with 3 different exercises (i.e. group 1 has pushups, pull-ups and dips).

I am to choose one exercise from each group to make a "round".

So how many rounds can I come up with using one exercise from each group and not repeating any exercise?

Also, is there a way to plug this into Excel to see all the possibilities?

Comment: Does each group have a unique set of exercises?

Comment: Yes, an exercise is only used onnce

Answer (score 0):

If no group can do the same exercise twice, you are limited to 3 rounds: after the third round, what is group 1 to do?

If you mean that the combination of 5 group exercises cannot be repeated, then there can be as many as $3^5=243$ rounds. Indeed, there are $3$ choices for each of $5$ groups, which can be made independently.

Here is a way to generate all 243 combinations in Excel. The exercises are coded as 0,1,2; you can use conditional operators like

```
=IF(B4=0,"push-ups",IF(B4=1,"pull-ups","dips"))
```

(different for each column B-F) to give them actual names. The codes are just consecutive integers; divisors are the powers of 3. The cells in boldface are computed with the formula

```
=MOD(FLOOR($A4/B$2,1),3)
```

(example for `B4` given)

[image: excel]